# Runtime Error caused by: Cannot read property ‘name’ of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am passing parameters in nav.push and setting a new root in the same function from side menu link, so I can set different tabs for the page.

```
viewItem(item){
this.navCtrl.push(ItemPage,{
item: item
});
this.navCtrl.setRoot(ItemtabsPage);
}
```

When I go to Item page I get the following error:

```
Runtime Error Error in ./ItemPage class ItemPage - caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

It works fine, If I don't set a new root or If I don't send any parameter. But I need to send Pratameter to Item Page and set new root so I can display different tabs. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you passing `item` into `viewItem(item){...}`? Can you show that code?

Comment: @Und3rTow I'm passing it by a simple click event `(click)="viewItem(item.Group)"`

Comment: ok and if you `console.log(item)` before `this.navCtrl.push(ItemPage,{...}` do you get what you are expecting?

Comment: @Und3rTow Yes I get the full object as expected. If I remove `this.navCtrl.setRoot(ItemtabsPage);` I get no errors and I get all the data as expected on ItemPage

Comment: Looking around online, I see that a lot of people have had this particular problem with `setRoot` and it seems like different solutions have worked for different set ups, so I would recommend perhaps going through [this issue on github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5883) and see if any of the solutions there work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Und3rTow I really appreciate it